# Redirect example.com to example.com/node

Tags: redirection

Currently I am facing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS problem in chrome when I try to visit `example.com`. Since `example.com/node` is working fine, I want to redirect all the traffic to `example.com/node` for now.

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any redirect module enabled? Might be because of that maybe Global redirect or something.

Otherwise you can redirect your homepage to pick up example.com/node by adding the path here: Default front page: URL(admin/config/system/site-information).

Comment: I don't have any redirect module enabled. By adding default front page through system/site-information it doesn't work. If someone types example.com I want to redirect him to example.com/node and this is not achieved by the this method. Anyways thanks for trying.